# Implement intent on RelativeLayout in ArrayList within a fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, fragment

I have a tour guide app I am working on where I have a set of four fragments. Each fragment has a set of CardViews with location address and hours. I want to implement a Google Maps intent that is triggered upon clicking the RelativeLayout which contains the address.

I have successfully been able to implement a Google Maps intent on the entire listview item, but I only want the RelativeLayout for the location TextView to trigger the intent upon clicking on it. These are the two snippets of code I have used in my fragment and only the first one works

```
//This snippet works, but on the entire listview
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String location = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location_text_view)).getText().toString();
        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + "+" + location + ", NYC");
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        startActivity(mapIntent);
        }
        });

//This one doesn't work at all, crashes the app
        RelativeLayout locationLayout =  listView.findViewById(R.id.location_layout);
        locationLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String location = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location_text_view)).getText().toString();
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + "+" + location + ", NYC");
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                startActivity(mapIntent);
            }
        });
```

> MiscellaneousFragment.java

```
package com.example.android.tourguideapp;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MiscellaneousFragment extends Fragment {


    public MiscellaneousFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);

        //Create an ArrayList for Place, Description, Location, Hours, and Image
        final ArrayList<Subjects> words = new ArrayList<Subjects>();
        words.add(new Subjects(getString(R.string.the_highline),
                getString(R.string.the_highline_des),
                getString(R.string.the_highline_loc),
                getString(R.string.the_highline_hours),
                R.drawable.the_highline));
        words.add(new Subjects(getString(R.string.st_john),
                getString(R.string.st_john_des),
                getString(R.string.st_john_loc),
                getString(R.string.st_john_hours),
                R.drawable.st_john));
        words.add(new Subjects(getString(R.string.chelsea_market),
                getString(R.string.chelsea_market_des),
                getString(R.string.chelsea_market_loc),
                getString(R.string.chelsea_market_hours),
                R.drawable.chelsea_market));

        SubjectsAdapter adapter = new SubjectsAdapter(getActivity(), words);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Google Maps intent upon clicking on the card
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String location = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location_text_view)).getText().toString();
        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + "+" + location + ", NYC");
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        startActivity(mapIntent);
        }
        });

//Commented out for experimental purposes
        /**RelativeLayout locationLayout =  listView.findViewById(R.id.location_layout);
        locationLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String location = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location_text_view)).getText().toString();
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + "+" + location + ", NYC");
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                startActivity(mapIntent);
            }
        });**/
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

> list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tour_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="194dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                tools:src="@drawable/dscn0585" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/place_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="bottom|left"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:textColor="#de000000"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:text="Place" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:lines="3"
                    android:textColor="#99000000"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:background="#12000000" />

//Layout I want with intent
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/location_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/location_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_location_on_48pt_3x" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/location_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/location_text_view"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/location_image_view"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#99000000"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:text="Location" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/hours_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/hours_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_access_time_48pt_3x" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hours_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/hours_image_view"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#99000000"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:text="Hours" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

> SubjectsAdapter.java

```
package com.example.android.tourguideapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SubjectsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Subjects> {
    public SubjectsAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Subjects> words) {
        super(context, 0, words);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the object position in the list
        Subjects currentSubject = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        TextView placeTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.place_text_view);
        placeTextView.setText(currentSubject.getPlace());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.description_text_view);
        descriptionTextView.setText(currentSubject.getDescription());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        TextView locationTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.location_text_view);
        locationTextView.setText(currentSubject.getLocation());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        TextView hoursTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.hours_text_view);
        hoursTextView.setText(currentSubject.getHours());

        // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        ImageView tourImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tour_image_view);
        tourImageView.setImageResource(currentSubject.getImageResourceId());

        // Return the list layout (4 TextViews and 1 ImageView)
        // so that it can be shown in the ListView
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

> SubjectsAdapter.java AFTER EDIT

```
package com.example.android.tourguideapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SubjectsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Subjects> {
    private Context mContext;

    /**Removed "Activity" and replaced with "Context"**/
    public SubjectsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Subjects> words) {
        super(context, 0, words);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the object position in the list
        Subjects currentSubject = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        TextView placeTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.place_text_view);
        placeTextView.setText(currentSubject.getPlace());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.description_text_view);
        descriptionTextView.setText(currentSubject.getDescription());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        TextView locationTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.location_text_view);
        locationTextView.setText(currentSubject.getLocation());


        RelativeLayout locationLayout = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.location_layout);
        locationLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String location = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location_text_view)).getText().toString();
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + "+" + location + ", NYC");
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                mContext.startActivity(mapIntent);
            }
        });

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        TextView hoursTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.hours_text_view);
        hoursTextView.setText(currentSubject.getHours());

        // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        ImageView tourImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tour_image_view);
        tourImageView.setImageResource(currentSubject.getImageResourceId());

        // Return the list layout (4 TextViews and 1 ImageView)
        // so that it can be shown in the ListView
        return listItemView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you paste your SubjectsAdapter? The problem is that you have to define interface for clicking on address inside your SubjectsAdapter. And you need to implement that interface in your MiscellaneousFragment.

Comment: Pasted and posted, thanks.

Comment: The problem I have with the code you provided is that I need it to be implemented on the RelativeLayout and not the TextView.

Comment: I edited my answer. It was small change, you should just find your layout by id, and then set onClickListener on it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain. I came up with a simpler solution where it is not passed through the fragments, but instead, onClick event is solely handled in the adapter. Not sure if this is bad practice. I have edited the code of the adapter to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by defining interface (OnAddressClickListener in this example) in your adapter. The logic is next: you define interface, and you make it as variable in your adapter. Then from your fragment, you define logic that should be triggered in your adapter, when address is clicked. Now it is only left to define setOnClickListener on your addressView, and trigger onAddressClickListener variable from your adapter, which was defined from fragment. It should look like this

```
public class SubjectsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Subjects> {

    private OnAddressClickListener onAddressClickListener;

    public void setOnAddressClickListener(OnAddressClickListener onAddressClickListener) {
        this.onAddressClickListener = onAddressClickListener;
    }

    public SubjectsAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Subjects> words) {
        super(context, 0, words);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the object position in the list
        Subjects currentSubject = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        TextView placeTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.place_text_view);
        placeTextView.setText(currentSubject.getPlace());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.description_text_view);
        descriptionTextView.setText(currentSubject.getDescription());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        TextView locationTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.location_text_view);
        locationTextView.setText(currentSubject.getLocation());


        // Trigger onAddressClickListener
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.location_layout);
        relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (onAddressClickListener != null)
                    onAddressClickListener.onAddressClick();
            }
        });

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        TextView hoursTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.hours_text_view);
        hoursTextView.setText(currentSubject.getHours());

        // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID
        ImageView tourImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tour_image_view);
        tourImageView.setImageResource(currentSubject.getImageResourceId());

        // Return the list layout (4 TextViews and 1 ImageView)
        // so that it can be shown in the ListView
        return listItemView;
    }

    public interface OnAddressClickListener {
        void onAddressClick();
    }
}
```

Now it is only left for you to implement this interface in your Fragment, and pass that value in your adapter.

```
SubjectsAdapter adapter = new SubjectsAdapter(getActivity(), words);
adapter.setOnAddressClickListener(new OnAddressClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onAddressClick() {
        // Here goes your login for starting new Intent
    }
});
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest and encourage you about using RecyclerView for your lists instead of ListView. RecyclerView is a more advanced and flexible version of ListView.

With this [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview), you can implement it easily and using the interface listener pattern you can set a click listener to each list item, are even you can pass the click listener to the adapter so every item can have this behavior.